# How to identify the signal 11 error reason?

Tags: linux, c++11, compiler-errors

I´m running a C++ program in a Linux system (Kernel 4.15 - Ubuntu 16.04). When I want to compile my code, I get the signal 11 error message which is related to line 10 ("for" loop) of the following code:

```
 void ProfilerBlock::ReadStack(const trace::EventValue& event,
                          std::vector<std::string>* stack)
 {
  process_t pid = ProcessForEvent(event);

  std::vector<std::string> symbolizedStack;
  const auto* stackField = 
  value::ArrayValue::Cast(event.getEventField("stack"));

  for (const auto& addressValue : *stackField)
    {
    uint64_t address = addressValue.AsULong();

    symbols::Symbol symbol;
    uint64_t offset = 0;
    if (!_symbols.LookupSymbol(address, _images[pid], &symbol, 
    &offset))
        symbol.set_name("Unknown Symbol");
    if (boost::starts_with(symbol.name(), "lttng_profile"))
        continue;

    stack->push_back(symbol.name());

    if (_dumpStacks)
        std::cout << symbol.name() << " - " << address << std::endl;
     }

     if (_dumpStacks)
        std::cout << std::endl;
     }
```

Does anybody have any idea about it?

Comment: The `auto* stackField = ...` looks a little unusual to me. If GCC is crashing during compile, then you should reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then file a [bug report with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/). Not many people get that badge.

Comment: The whole code is here:

https://github.com/fdoray/tibeecompare/blob/master/src/stacks_blocks/ProfilerBlock.cpp

Comment: If I had to guess: `event.getEventField("stack")` returns some temporary object by value. Then you obtain a pointer to something inside that object. Then that object is destroyed at the semicolon, leaving the pointer dangling. Then you dereference that pointer, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik :  No, I tried that but the result is the same.

Comment: You tried what?